# Remove header from response if empty with HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I'm in a situation whereas apparently something in my backend is setting a blank Set-Cookie. This only happens on Chrome.

It might also be some kind of extension but in order to verify I'd like to remove from the backend response the Set-Cookie header if it results empty, but I'm not sure what I should write as condition.

```
http-request del-header Set-Cookie if <condition>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try out the following, either in your `frontend` or `backend` section(s):

```
acl set_cookie_len res.hdr(Set-Cookie) -m len 0
rspidel Set-Cookie if set_cookie_len
```

What this does:

1. Checks the length of the `Set-Cookie` header against 0; evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
2. Removes the response header if `set_cookie_len` is `TRUE`.

Some notes:

- I couldn't test this right now, so any feedback is appreciated.
- AFAIK `del-header` is used to delete request headers, but, if I understood you correctly, you want to modify response headers, right?

Comment: To be more precise `del-header` is not for request or at least not just for requests. You can use `http-response del-header`

Comment: Heads up for anyone reading this answer in 2021:

The 'rspidel' directive is not supported anymore since HAProxy 2.1. 
Use 'http-response del-header' instead.
Source: the haproxy.log after trying to start haproxy with this directive in its config ;)